# Как победить повышенную активность WAL?

Tags: база-данных, postgresql

Есть маленькая база данных, которая содержит несколько таблиц. Данные в этих таблицах не критичны, поэтому все они заданы как `UNLOGGED`.

Так вот, я не понимаю, почему постгресовский *`wal writer process`* постоянно что-то пишет в лог? Вроде при изменении `UNLOGGED` таблицы ничего в **WAL** записываться не должно.

Или я чего-то недопонимаю?